# Creating new worksheets based on pivot table values in the same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried running the following code to create new worksheets based on pivot table row lables....

```
 Sub test()
Dim lastrow As Long, x As Long, CurWs As Worksheet

lastrow = Sheets("Pivot Table").cells.Find("*", cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row

With Sheets("Pivot Table")
For x = 6 To lastrow - 1
  Set CurWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
 CurWs.Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PivotTable").cells(x, 1)
Next x
End With


End Sub
```

The line `Set CurWs` where I get the runtime error 429 "AciveX Compnonent Can create object" again on the same line

Comment: Why are you using both `ThisWorkbook` and `ActiveWorkbook` in that line? That inconsistency is probably the problem.

Comment: Note that Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. Therefore `Dim x As Long`.

Comment: @BigBen I amended code as recommended, getting a different issue now

Comment: @Pᴇʜ having a different issue now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Tidy up your code. Eg. only reference a worksheet by its name once. If you do that multiple times you easily run into typos. Furthermore if its name ever changes you will have to change it in **every** place. If you reference it to a variable then you only have to change it once.
- Format it nicely to see your issues.
- Don't mix `Sheets` and `Worksheets` they are not the same. `Worksheets` contains only worksheets but `Sheets` contains all kind of sheets like worksheets, chart sheets, etc. Especially when using counts of worksheets/sheets they might have a different `.Count`. So use the one you actually need and don't mix them.
- Make sure **every** `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows` and `Columns` object has a worksheet referenced. Here `Find("*", cells(1, 1)` the `Cells` object has no worksheet reference and therefore Excel might fail guessing the right worksheet if you don't specify it explicitly.

```vb
Option Explicit 

Public Sub test()
    Dim PivotSheet As Worksheet
    Set PivotSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot Table")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = PivotSheet.Cells.Find("*", PivotSheet.Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row

    Dim x As Long
    For x = 6 To LastRow - 1
        Dim CurWs As Worksheet
        Set CurWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
        CurWs.Name = PivotSheet.Cells(x, 1)
    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is with space `Sheets("Pivot Table")` and here it is without `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PivotTable").Cells(x, 1)`

It wouldn't be that?